# Unity 2D: Why does my character stutter if I add deltaTime to moveSpeed?

Tags: unity, 2d, movement

So I'm following a tutorial on youtube, first time Unity user, but been making games in other frameweorks before. In the tutorial he does not use deltaTime for movement, which has always been the standard for me, so I added it my self, but it makes my character "stutter/lag" really weirdly (does not stutter without deltaTime). Surely I must use deltaTime for movement in the `Update()`method?

Script for Player movement:

```
void Update () {

     playerMoving = false;

     if (!playerAttacking) {
         Vector2 direction = new Vector2();

         if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal")) > 0.5f) {
             Debug.Log ("Moving on X");
             playerMoving = true; 
             direction.x = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"); 
             lastMove.x = direction.x;
             lastMove.y = 0;
         }

         if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical")) > 0.5f) {
             Debug.Log ("Moving on Y");
             playerMoving = true; 
             direction.y = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical"); 
             lastMove.y = direction.y;
             lastMove.x = 0;
         }

             if (playerMoving) { 
                 myRigidBody.velocity = direction.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
             } else { 
                 myRigidBody.velocity = Vector2.zero; 
             }
     }
```

My Camera (Stutters unless I use fixedUpdate):

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    targetPos = new Vector3 (followTarget.transform.position.x, followTarget.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, targetPos, moveSpeed);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting [velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html). Since it goes without saying that `distance = time x velocity`, what you're doing now is `distance = time x (velocity x time)`. If you were setting the [position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) of your object, then multiplying by delta time would have made sense.

In short, you shouldn't be multiplying velocity by time. Again, if it was something like acceleration that you were using, since `velocity = time x acceleration`, the formula would've changed as follows:

```
myRigidBody.velocity = myRigidBody.velocity + (direction.normalized * acceleration * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: @Green_qaue I've updated the answer to include acceleration and how you should be using the velocity if you want an "overtime change". Don't forget to set a maximum value for your velocity (an if condition and checking for maximum velocity should be fine).

Comment: Thanks. So is setting velocity without deltaTime fine, or should I change so I set Position, instead of velocity, and use deltaTime? For normal movement

Comment: Ah, I jsut read the docs, okay so I should not use velocity for this. Maybe I shouild stop folowing this tutorial

Comment: @Green_qaue since you already have coding and other framework experience, I suggest just making a simple scene to learn the ropes and search for what you need online instead of sticking to a tutorial.

Comment: One more question, should I be controlling movement inside Update or FixedUpdate? Simply setting `myRigidBody.position += direction.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime` Didn't work. I see some people using `addForce` inside FixedUpdate, for movement

Comment: @Green_qaue you should be using FixedUpdate for everything that has a RigidBody reference on them. FixedUpdate is physics update (which happens in a set amount of time, every single time), the other one is frame by frame update (which is variable). (P.S. you don't have to use all RigidBody references in FixedUpdate, but doing so is usually better.)

Comment: So really I could just use `rigidbody.setVelocity`, but it needs to be inside `FixedUpdate();` . Since `AddForce` adds acceleration, which I dont want. And doing `rigidBody.position += x` makes it stutter like crazy.